# Unable to establish a connection even after configuring bridges

Tags: windows

This is what my log looks like. Please help.

```
21/11/2016 23:58:29 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
21/11/2016 23:58:29 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
21/11/2016 23:58:29 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
21/11/2016 23:58:29 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
21/11/2016 23:58:36 PM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
21/11/2016 23:58:36 PM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50001 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
21/11/2016 23:58:36 PM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:7920 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
21/11/2016 23:58:37 PM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.95.36.142:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
21/11/2016 23:58:38 PM.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
21/11/2016 23:58:38 PM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:7013 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
21/11/2016 23:58:39 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
21/11/2016 23:58:39 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
21/11/2016 23:58:39 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/11/2016 0:06:29 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:06:29 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:06:29 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:06:29 AM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/11/2016 0:07:34 AM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 7; recommendation warn; host B9E7141C594AF25699E0079C1F0146F409495296 at 0.0.2.0:2) 
22/11/2016 0:07:34 AM.800 [WARN] 18 connections have failed: 
22/11/2016 0:07:34 AM.800 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
22/11/2016 0:07:34 AM.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED 
22/11/2016 0:07:34 AM.800 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
22/11/2016 0:07:34 AM.800 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
22/11/2016 0:08:19 AM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/11/2016 0:08:19 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:08:19 AM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/11/2016 0:08:59 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:08:59 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:08:59 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:08:59 AM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/11/2016 0:09:16 AM.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host D1323EF7D00E20056F5E8D9929639F6C3359688D at 124.210.165.77:443) 
22/11/2016 0:09:16 AM.000 [WARN] 21 connections have failed: 
22/11/2016 0:09:16 AM.000 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
22/11/2016 0:09:16 AM.000 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED 
22/11/2016 0:09:16 AM.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
22/11/2016 0:09:16 AM.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
22/11/2016 0:09:47 AM.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/11/2016 0:09:47 AM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/11/2016 0:09:47 AM.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Can you view https://a0.awsstatic.com/ or https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least TLS/SSL MitM attacks in your network( by meaning lines like 'X connections died in state handshaking' with SSL or TLS mentioned ), so if Meek pluggable transport(that is designed specially for such a cases) does not work - try to use obfs3/4 *private* bridges with fingerprints/keys. Private bridge is not published, so it looks like a usual Tor node to the world, only some people know about it and it's lakely all the Tor nodes will be banned in a real time - it's quite laborious and almost useless. If you add more details to your question I'll be able to help you better

UPDATE: I've added some clarification as asked in a post anonymous comment. If you need some extra/specific info - please tell what exactly do you want.